# Finding a good replacement for Rnd in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, random, numbers

The Rnd function in Excel is known to be weak, whereas the RAND function in Excel is based on the Mersenne algorithm and much stronger. I've been trying to find a fast and strong alternative to Rnd, and looked at various options, including the use of Mersenne, but this requires a lot of code.

Comment: I have an algorithm (I got is somewhere long time ago) based on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichmann%E2%80%93Hill . If it would be helpful, I can copy as an answer.

Comment: thank you, I’ve seen that, and it is fast but I don’t know how reliable it is.

Comment: If the only problem to use Mersene, that it required a lot of coding. I have found a version on this page: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/BASIC/basic.html

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to call the Excel RAND function from VBA, but this is extremely slow when done one at a time. However, the new function RANDARRAY in Excel365 allows VBA to call a large quantity of random numbers from Excel in one go, use them as needed, and go back for more when necessary. This approach is fast (only 4x slower than Rnd, and faster than Mersenne code) and compact - the code is below.

I'm sharing this in the hope of finding the best collective solution to this problem.

```
Function RandXL() As Single
  Static Remaining As Long, R() As Variant
  If Remaining = 0 Then 'get more numbers if necessary
    R = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandArray(1000, 1)
    Remaining = 1000
  End If
  RandXL = R(Remaining, 1)
  Remaining = Remaining - 1
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use truly random numbers - as shown in my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).

It contains a direct replacement for *Rnd*:

```vb
' Returns a true random number as a Double, like Rnd returns a Single.
' The value will be less than 1 but greater than or equal to zero.
'
' Usage: Excactly like Rnd:
'
'   TrueRandomValue = RndQrn[(Number)]
'
'   Number < 0  ->  The same number every time, using Number as the seed.
'   Number > 0  ->  The next number in the pseudo-random sequence.
'   Number = 0  ->  The most recently generated number.
'   No Number   ->  The next number in the pseudo-random sequence.
'
' 2019-12-21. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RndQrn( _
    Optional ByVal Number As Single = 1) _
    As Double
    
    Static Value            As Double
    
    Select Case Number
        Case Is > 0 Or (Number = 0 And Value = 0)
            ' Return the next number in the random sequence.
            Value = CDbl(QrnDecimal)
        Case Is = 0
            ' Return the most recently generated number.
        Case Is < 0
            ' Not supported by QRN.
            ' Retrieve value from RndDbl.
            Value = RndDbl(Number)
    End Select
    
    ' Return a value like:
    ' 0.171394365283966
    RndQrn = Value
    
End Function
```

Also, a demo (`RandomQrn.xlsm`) is included to download.

This has set a Reference to *Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library* which has the *Nz* function used. If you prefer not to have this reference, this substitute will do:

```vb
' Replacement for the function Application.Nz() of Access.
'
' 2015-12-10. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Nz( _
    ByRef Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef ValueIfNull As Variant = "") _
    As Variant

    Dim ValueNz     As Variant
    
    If Not IsEmpty(Value) Then
        If IsNull(Value) Then
            ValueNz = ValueIfNull
        Else
            ValueNz = Value
        End If
    End If
        
    Nz = ValueNz
    
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, Gustav. It seems to do a web query to retrieve random numbers. I don't see how that is going to be very fast, and if you don't have an internet connection, or your website is down, what do you do?

How well does it go with all the test suites for randomness, eg Diehard?

Comment: It depends how you weight "fast" and "stronger" and how you measure - we don't know. Please note, that you can retrieve a batch of numbers as an array which is the fastest collection you can have in VBA. As for randomness, study the sources to which I have provided links in the documentation. If you cannot rely on an internet connections - which seems weird these days - go to Quantis and purchase the add-inn PCI card; that will also provide the ultimate speed (at a cost).

Comment: Two things
1. the code throws an error when it sees Nz undefined
2. your documentation doesn't test the method using any of the standard test suites

Comment: The demo has set a Reference to Access to reach _Nz_ - see edited answer, please. Also, please understand, that the goal with my project is not to prove the randomness of the source (which I have no reason to doubt) but to show how this great source easily can be taken advantage of in VBA, specifically Access and Excel. If you happen to run any of these tests, I will be happy to include the results in the documentation.

Comment: It’s a nice idea, not what I’m looking for, but others may need very quality randomness.
I would suggest running some of the formal randomness tests to make sure it is as random as you believe, and also that there is no error in the implementation.

Comment: If you could guide me to some VB(A) (or C#) implementations of the Diehard tests, I would love to.

Comment: there are many references to them on the net. There is one called Crusher something. I’m not expert in this so I don’t know them offhand, but I can see that anybody who wants their method taken seriously, needs to show they can pass the tests.